# javascript: What is the difference between anonymous function and declared function?

Tags: javascript

This is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CGAb7/

```
$( ".tweet1" ).click(function() {
    alert( "this is tweet1" );
});  

$('.tweet2').click(tryAlert());
  function tryAlert(){
    alert('this is tweet2');
  }
```

Why is the second version(declared function) get run automatically?

Comment: because you are calling it in the `click` argument, you are wanting to pass it, eg leave off the `()`

Comment: You can reuse `tryAlert`.

Comment: Additionally, for debugging purposes named functions are better than anonymous. In a contrived example like yours it probably makes good sense to use anonymous function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to pass a function as a parameter, you omit the `()`, in your case:

```
$('.tweet2').click(tryAlert);
```

This allows the function to be called when needed. Adding `()` invokes the function immediately.